# How to install an app in MI Note 4?

Tags: android, usb, adb, miui

When i  pressed “Install via USB” in MI Note 4 then the message “The device is temporarily restricted” poped up.Can anyone  tell me how to run android app in MI Note 4 through Android Studio?

Comment: Was your device locked during app installation?

Comment: Doesn't seem like a programming question. Try editing according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) or posting to a more appropriate [sister site](https://stackexchange.com/sites) - sorry, dunno which would be best off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

In MI devices there are some more restriction because of which Install via usb doesn't work, do this

here's solution that helped me:
1. Settings ->  Additional Settings -> Developer options -> Turn off Miui Optimizations -> Restart
2. Security -> Permissions -> Gear Icon at top right corner -> Turn On "Install via USB"
3. Settings ->  Additional Settings -> Developer options -> Turn On/Off "USB Debugging" -> Turn On "Install vis USB"

Comment: Step 1 have worked for every one, try that.